# How to use company-c-headers on Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I am new to emacs and using emacs 25.1 on windows.

I followed [this article](https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#orgheadline16) to set up `company-c-headers`

I added following code to init.el

```
(require 'company-c-headers)
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)
(add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-system "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include")
(add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-system "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/atlmfc/include")
```

I added following code to `.dir-locals.el` which is placed under the root of my testing project.

```
(add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-user "D:/Work/Learning/Emacs/my_program/my_inc/")
```

After started emacs and opened `D:/Work/Learning/Emacs/my_program/src/main.cpp`. Under `*Message*`, I got `.dir-locals error: Wrong type argument: listp, add-to-list`.

How to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that you have added to `.dir-locals.el` is wrong.  This file has a special format, described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

If I'm not mistaken, the line that you should add to `.dir-locals.el` should be:

```
((nil . ((company-c-headers-path-user . ("D:/Work/Learning/Emacs/my_program/my_inc/")))))
```

Notice that this line sets the list `company-c-headers-path-user` to contain just that one directory; it does not add this directory to the list.